# .NET Client for Apache Kafka

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

Is there any recommended .NET Client for Apache Kafka that supports headers and has an official release?

(I saw that currently "confluent-kafka-dotnet" client does not support headers.
reference - https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/issues/393)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to my conversation (https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/issues/393) with @mhowlett (One of the collaborators in Confluent-Kafka-Dotnet"), there is not yet official version that supports headers. Only the CI version that is: 0.11.3-ci-280 and above supports headers.

Official version will be out when this PR will be closed-

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/pull/431

If you have more questions, you can ask me:)

Have a nice day!

Comment: update, follow this - https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/issues/472